# Vim: remove line numbers and colorcolumn from quickfix window

Tags: vim, vimrc

In my vimrc I have both `set number` and `set colorcolumn=80`, so now when I open a quickfix window, I see both line numbers and the color column. Is there some way to disable these settings for quickfix windows only? (If it matters, I'm on OSX using vim 7.3).

Thanks!

Comment: Note that line numbers may be a bit useful with `cc <line-number>` of `<line-number>G<enter>` to jump to an error you see.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the following into `~/.vim/ftplugin/qf.vim`:

```
setlocal nonumber
setlocal colorcolumn=
```

As long as you have filetype plugin support enabled, that should handle it.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks. I didn't know about this, very useful.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind having an extra line in your `~/.vimrc` instead:

```
au FileType qf setlocal nonumber colorcolumn=
```